# Max value of seaborn boxplot did not equivalent to Q3+1.5*IQR

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I would like to create a `boxplot` with maximum value of `Q3+1.5xIQR` to identify the outliers. However, the maximum value does not seem to tally with calculated value of `Q3+1.5xIQR`. Appreciate help to rectify it.

Taking 'A' as an example, why did the whisker plot at '60' instead of '85'? On a side note, I inserted 'whis=1.5' in command.

```
Q3+1.5xIQR =47.5+1.5x(47.5-22.5) =85
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You didn't provide any test data nor reproducible code?  See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot): *"Another popular choice for the boundaries of the whiskers is based on the 1.5 IQR value. From above the upper quartile (Q3), a distance of 1.5 times the IQR is measured out and a whisker is drawn up to the largest observed data point from the dataset that falls within this distance."*  So, up till the largest input data point within `Q3 + 1.5 IQR`.  What do you want to "rectify"?

Comment: @JohanC post edited to include snapshots.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Did you understand the comment from the wikipedia article? Doesn't that explain your issue? Please clearly explain what you need to have different, if seaborn is using the most common definition (which makes a lot of sense: why would you draw a line unrelated to the data?). The idea of a boxplot is to give a rough idea of the given data. Note that datasets may be very shifted to one side, have thick tails etc. The definition of a boxplot should work with most of them. In your `A` case: all values larger than `60` would be outliers. Isn't that a very logical plot?

Comment: Thanks. Clarification needed for new arising doubts below. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) states, under the `whis` parameter; emphasis mine:

> whis: float or pair of floats
>
> Paramater that controls whisker length. If scalar, whiskers are drawn **to the farthest datapoint within whis * IQR** from the nearest hinge. If a tuple, it is interpreted as percentiles that whiskers represent.

So if the farthest (maximum or minimum) datapoint is within 1.5 * IQR, the whisker is drawn to that datapoint, and not to 1.5 * IQR. If I understand correctly, the whisker will never be drawn to exactly 1.5 * IQR, unless a data point at that value exist.

In your example, the farthest datapoint within 1.5 * IQR above Q3 is 60, so the whisker is only drawn to 60.

This also agrees with the comment and Wikipedia quote by JohanC.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I am getting closer to clear the doubts. That being said, could you extend your help to respond the following enquiries? 

1) Is the statement below correct?

The highest side of whisker is drawn to: 
Maximum datapoint (if it is within 1.5 * IQR) or 
1.5 * IQR (if there is a data point existing at 1.5 * IQR or the maximum datapoint exceeding 1.5 * IQR) 

2) In Case A, is it true that the lowest side of whisker is drawn to 10?

Comment: @Tong 1/ No: the whisker is drawn to the largest datapoint within 1.5 * IQR even if there is another value exceeding 1.5 * IQR; it is not drawn to exactly 1.5 * IQR. This is easy to show: `sns.boxplot([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 55, 95])` shows the whisker extends to 55, while the 1.5 * IQR range is 93.75; 95 is plotted separately. 2/ Yes. (Again, you can easily show this. It is, in fact, shown in your own example; so I'm not sure why you are asking this.)

Comment: I am clear as of now . Thank you!